# ndb - node debugger does not launch after being installed trough npm

Tags: node.js, npm, google-chrome-devtools

After installing `ndb`, I have tried starting `ndb` with it doing nothing and throwing no errors. Headless chrome does not launch.

I ran the following commands without any errors :

```
sudo npm i ndb --global
```

after that I ran:

`ndb server.js`(server.js is in the root of the folder running the command in wls: '`node server.js`'  works fine- I am also not running this command while trying to use nbd)

This does not seem to do anything and no errors are thrown

I have also tried running the command "`ndb .`"  with nothing happening as well.
I have tried saving as a dev dependency with similar results
I have restarted my machine and visual studio

```
**Node version** 10.23.0 

**Google Chrome** Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**NPM version** 6.14.8
```

//output from WSL

```
user@MSI:/mnt/d/Coding/Node-Tutorial/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours$ sudo npm i ndb --gloabl
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN natours@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ ndb@1.1.5
updated 1 package and audited 268 packages in 7.935s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

user@MSI:/mnt/d/Coding/Node-Tutorial/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours$ ndb server.js

user@MSI:/mnt/d/Coding/Node-Tutorial/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours$ // *No errors thrown just returned back  to command line*
```

**Server.js code**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});
const app = require('./app');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace('<PASSWORD>',process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD);

mongoose.connect(DB,{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(con =>{
  // console.log(con.connections);
  console.log('DB')


});

// Server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`listend ${port}`);
});

// console.log(process.env)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to launch chromium from ndb because you are using WSL and wsl cannot have a GUI output as it is just terminal based. To use ndb you need to use either command prompt or powershell (for a windows machine) to launch chromium with ndb.